# AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'admin_order_field'

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to be able to define a property in a Model that can also be displayed AND sort using admin_order_field in the 'list_display' Admin property. Below is the code for a property that I wanted to define (and be sortable in the django admin interface)

```
  @property
  def restaurant_name(self):
    return str(self.restaurant)
  restaurant_name.admin_order_field = 'restaurant__name'
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'admin_order_field'
```

When I get rid of the @property decorator, it works fine, but then I have to call restaurant_name() on model instances, instead of restaurant_name, which provides inconsistent style in how I access different properties of the model (which are actually defined as Python properties). How do I specify a Python property as sortable in the admin?

Comment: This property is superficial, you can simply do `obj.restaurant` where _obj_ is an instance of the model. So, why do you have this property exactly?

Comment: So I can sort the current Model by the foreign key in the admin interface. This example is somewhat superficial, but there are other instances in my code where a property definition makes a lot more sense than a function

Comment: `So I can sort the current Model by the foreign key in the admin interface.` - use a callable or a field in the model. A property is not callable.

Comment: So basically it's impossible to define a property on a model to also provide sorting capability in admin interface?

Comment: Its not impossible - as long as the property isn't the thing you want to order by.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't assign attributes to a property, just like the error message is telling you. You have two options - remove the @property decorator, or provide a wrapper that only the admin uses.

```
@property
def restaurant_name(self):
    return str(self.restaurant)

def restaurant_name_admin(self):
    return self.restaurant_name

restaurant_name_admin.admin_order_field = 'restaurant__name'
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar with Josh answer but a bit pretty and useful for me because this way also allow you `short_description` specifying:

```
def _restaurant_name(self):
  return str(self.restaurant)
_restaurant_name.short_description = ugettext_lazy("restaurant name")
_restaurant_name.admin_order_field = 'restaurant__name'
restaurant_name = property(_restaurant_name)
```

Now you can use `_restaurant_name` as callable in admin changelist_view and `restaurant_name` as a property anywhere else.